# Pandas: Splitting a Row Into Multiple Rows Efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

The problem I am currently facing is taking a pandas DataFrame and efficiently taking each record and breaking it down into multiple records in the following way:

Input:

```
In [16]: pd.DataFrame({'Name': 'Person1', 'State': 'Indiana', 'Money1': 100.42, 'Money2':54.54, 'Money3': 23.45}, index=[1])
Out[16]: 
   Money1  Money2  Money3  Name     State
1  100.42  54.54   23.45   Person1  Indiana
```

Output:

```
   Money1  Money2  Money3  Name     State
1  100.42  np.nan  np.nan  Person1  Indiana 
2  np.nan  54.54   np.nan  Person1  Indiana      
3  np.nan  np.nan  23.45   Person1  Indiana
```

Essentially, the problem is splitting the original record into x records where x is a list of passed in columns to split by (in this case 'Money1', 'Money2', 'Money3'. I have tried doing this by creating DataFrames and concat'ing them but this is extremely slow and memory inefficient.

EDIT1:

Please not that the answer does not work if even one of your static columns (the ones that are turned into multi-indices) is full of NaN. This is a reported bug in pandas:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6322

To get around it, use `fillna` or `replace` to fill in columns comprised entirely of `NaN` with empty string `''`, for example, and then after this process, put the `NaN` back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for a dataframe with an arbitrary number of columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Person1', 'Person2'], 
                   'State': ['Indiana', 'NY'], 
                   'Money1': [100.42, 200], 
                   'Money2': [54.54, 25], 
                   'Money3': [23.45, 10]})

index_cols = ['Name', 'State']
cols = [c for c in df if c not in index_cols]

df2 = df.set_index(index_cols).stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).to_frame('Value')

df2 = pd.concat([pd.Series([v if i % len(cols) == n else np.nan 
                            for i, v in enumerate(df2.Value)], name=col) 
                 for n, col in enumerate(cols)], axis=1).set_index(df2.index)

>>> df2.reset_index()
      Name    State  Money1  Money2  Money3
0  Person1  Indiana       1     NaN     NaN
1  Person1  Indiana     NaN      55     NaN
2  Person1  Indiana     NaN     NaN      23
3  Person2       NY       2     NaN     NaN
4  Person2       NY     NaN      25     NaN
5  Person2       NY     NaN     NaN      10
```

Comment: Calling `df2.reset_index(drop=False)` gets it into the format I want after the above process.